# PHP $variable++ not working :(

Tags: php, syntax, foreach, operators

I have this code:

```
$arrayOfData = array("Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4", "Data5", "Data6", "Data7", "Data8", "Data9");

var $dataCounter = 0;
var $setCounter = 1;

foreach($arrayOfData as $row => $value){

    $this->$dataCounter++;

    if($this->$dataCounter == 3){
      $this->$setCounter++;
      $this->$dataCounter = 0;
    }


}
```

When I goto echo the $this->$setCounter all I get is 0. I am using PHP 4, is my syntax correct? My foreach is inside a function inside a class. My variables are inside the class.

Comment: No. You're not in a class, why are you using `$this`?

Comment: also you dont need to declare var in php. and array of data should be array("data1","data2",etc)

Comment: My foreach is inside a function inside a class. My variables are inside the class.

Comment: Why on earth are you using PHP 4!?!?!?

Comment: How about you paste the actual class. It seems you just picked out random lines and are backpeddling to keep up with what is required to actually fix your code.

Comment: @John V.: what if you have terribly (but extremely important) old legacy 100M LoC project (of course without unit tests) that works on php4? What would you do to extend it - continue using php4 or try to upgrade to php5?

Comment: @zerkms I'd wish I wasn't in such a position, but point taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this doesn't appear to be in a class, no, it is not correct. `$this->` is unecessary and incorrect as is your usage of `var`.

```
var $setCounter = 1;
// ...
$this->$setCounter++;
```

just needs to be:

```
$setCounter = 1;
// ...
$setCounter++;
```

The same applies to `$dataCounter`

**edit**

If you are using a class then you

1. should move `var $dataCounter = 0; var $setCounter = 1;` outside of your method.
2. change `$this->$setCounter++;` to `$this->setCounter++;`

Comment: this is the correct solution. another thing to note is that when you reference a classes properies in php you dont use the variable operator to do so, the correct syntax would be $this->setCounter++ not $this->$setCounter if you were inside of a class

Comment: My foreach is inside a function inside a class. My variables are inside the class.

Comment: var is still bad practice. it's either public, private, protected, etc.

Comment: @skrilled If they are using PHP4 they don't have much of a choice

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. Who the hell uses php4 nowadays ><

Answer (score 0):

`$foo->$bar` is a variable variable. You're not dealing with a `bar` member of the `foo` object, you're dealing with whatever value is stored in a separate `$bar` variable, which is used to look up a member of `$foo. e.g.

```
# Set up object
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->bar = 'bar';
$foo->foo = 'foo';

# Try to write to something in the object    
$x = 'bar';
$foo->$x = 'hello';  // note the $ on x
$foo->x = 'there';  // note the lack of $

var_dump($foo);

object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["bar"]=>
  string(5) "hello"   // because of $foo->$x
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["x"]=>
  string(5) "there"   // because of $foo->x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the keyword 'var' in PHP like you are.

I believe you need to look back at the basics. Check out the following link for more details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Also, you do not need the ->. You only use this if the left part is an object instance. You would use it to access instance members or static members (however, I'd suggest :: for static members). Check out the following link for more details:
[Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

As far as your code goes, remove the 'arrow's and the 'var's. You are echoing 0 because you initialized 'var $dataCounter' as 0.

```
    $arrayOfData = array("Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4", "Data5", "Data6", "Data7", "Data8", "Data9");

    $dataCounter = 0;
    $setCounter = 1;

    foreach($arrayOfData as $row => $value){

           $dataCounter++;

           if($dataCounter == 3) {
                $setCounter++;
                $dataCounter = 0;
           }
   }
```

Start from there and then continue. Also, for what you are doing a foreach is unnecessary. Instead:

```
    $arrayOfData = array("Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4", "Data5", "Data6", "Data7", "Data8", "Data9");

    $setCounter = (sizeOf($arrayOfData))%3; //counts sets of 3
```